# According to Catholicism, can someone sin in Heaven?

Tags: catholicism, sin, heaven

I know that  Christians who die still imperfectly purified must, according to Catholic teaching, pass through a state of purification known as purgatory before entering heaven. But does this automatically mean that after purification no one can sin anymore in Heaven?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Is choosing to commit sin a possibility in Heaven?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/79195/is-choosing-to-commit-sin-a-possibility-in-heaven)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is choosing to commit sin a possibility in Heaven?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/79195/is-choosing-to-commit-sin-a-possibility-in-heaven)